# Join two lists based on a condition other than equals

Tags: c#, linq

In a nutshell...

I have a list of source control folders which are gathered from changesets using the TFS API in the structure of:

> $/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project A
>
> $/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Subfolder/Project B
>
> $/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project C

The above will only have a select few projects included, I then have a list of all project names in the format of:

> Project A
>
> Project B
>
> Project C
>
> Project D

I am trying to select a new list which has a join between the two lists, and then get an anonymous type which contains the 1st structure, and the second structure. I think I should be using something like `Contains`, however the syntax only offers `equals` when trying to use a join.

I have tried:

```
var sourceFolders = new List<string>()
{ 
  "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project A",
  "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Sub-Folder/Project B",
  "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project C"
};
var projectNames = new List<string>() { "Project A", "Project B", "Project C", "Project D"};
var filteredProjects = sourceFolders.Where(sourceFolder => projectNames.Any(x => sourceFolder.Contains(x)));
```

`filteredProjects` will only contain `sourceFolders` however and not which `project` it has mapped too...

Any ideas?

**Desired output**

```
new { SourceFolder = "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project A", ProjectName  = "Project A" };
new { SourceFolder = "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Subfolder/Project B", ProjectName  = "Project B" };
new { SourceFolder = "$/ProjectFolder/BranchName/Project C", ProjectName  = "Project C" };
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what is your desired output. I'm assuming two lists you wrote here are the input.

Comment: @Dialecticus I assume you down-voted, I have posted the desired output - I thought that the explanation was pretty clear. I hope this has cleared things up :)

Comment: It is clear now, however I'm not your downvoter. You get +1 for effort, though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
var filteredProjects = sourceFolders
    .Select(sf => new { 
        Project = projectNames.FirstOrDefault(x => sf.Contains(x)),
        Folder = sf
    })
    .Where(o => o.Project != null);
```

This projects each source folder into an instance of an anonymous type with `Project` and `Folder` properties; the latter is the source folder, and the former is the name of the project (which may be `null` if `projectNames` has no match for a particular folder).

The result is then filtered to eliminate objects that correspond to folders which could not be associated with a project.

There is also the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx)-powered equivalent

```
var filteredProjects = sourceFolders
    .Select(sf => Tuple.Create(
        sf, projectNames.FirstOrDefault(x => sf.Contains(x))
    ))
    .Where(t => t.Item2 != null);
```

Comment: Ah I was over-complicating things... Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do it like this:

```
var filteredProjects = from source in sourceFolders
                       let project = projectNames.FirstOrDefault(p => source.Contains(p))
                       where project != null
                       select new {
                           SourceFolder = source,
                           Project = project
                       };
```